# Java sqlite error (error or missing database) no such table

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite

This is the class where I connect sqlite

```
public static Connection ConnectDB() { 
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\abh\\eclipse-workspace \\Training\\Database.db");
        return con;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The jar file inside the project folder name is sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2 I'm confused whether it's because of the version or if it's from my database created in sqlite

Comment: There is a space `\\eclipse-workspace \\...` in your path.
Is it expected?

Please share the full stacktrace to your error.

Comment: There was no space it showed up like this here only error is java.sql.SQLEXCEPTION: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table:database)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is a pretty good database platform, I highly doubt it's the problem as is the JDBC version your using as well.

The Connection method you presented does indeed work but you need to keep in mind that the connection has nothing to do with tables. It has everything to towards a connection to a particular SQLite database file and if the path doesn't exist to get to the database file specified, then it simply can not find that database. If the path does exist, and local system permissions allow it, and the database file does not exist, then the connection call will automatically create the database file specified but it will be empty. Never the less, the connection is now made and ready for a database Table to be either **Created** or Accessed via a query (providing there is actual data in the table).

If there was an error regards to the connection then you would receive a Message Box on the screen, and if you do then it's probably because of the whitespace that exists in the specified database path between `eclipse-workspace` and `\\Training`:

```
"jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\abh\\eclipse-workspace \\Training\\Database.db"
```

**Edit:** Oh...as already specified by @lazylead :)

**On a side:** It's not a good idea to hard-code the path to your database file. This will never be the path when the application is run in the real world.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I don't know how it showed that there was a space in the path maybe I presses space accidently when posting it. The problem is that I have the knowledge in eclipse only and my project concerns first in updating a certain database from a authenticated website. Any suggestion to what program I may use? (Also I created a database inside that connected sqllite)